# SQL Query returns duplicate component records

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables each related by job number:  OrderHeader, OrderComponent, OrderQtyTable.  This order has five components, when this query is run it returns 25 lines duplicating each component five times with the TotalPrice for each of the five components showing for each of the five components.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.OrderHeader.JobNumber,
    dbo.OrderComponent.ComponentNumber AS Comp,
    dbo.OrderHeader.JobDescription,
    dbo.OrderComponent.Description,
    dbo.OrderQtyTable.Quantity,
    dbo.OrderQtyTable.TotalPrice
FROM dbo.OrderHeader
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderComponent ON dbo.OrderHeader.JobNumber = dbo.OrderComponent.JobNumber
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderQtyTable ON dbo.OrderHeader.JobNumber = dbo.OrderQtyTable.JobNumber
WHERE (dbo.OrderHeader.JobNumber = '97180'
```

Comment: Is it possible to see the table definitions and the relation bewteen them?

Comment: Impossible to diagnose without sample data.

Comment: I'm quite sure there is a field that links OrderComponent and OrderQtyTable

Comment: JobNumber is key to all three tables, ComponentNumber links OrderComponent table and OrderQtyTable table.

Comment: Then adding ComponentNumber to the join condition of OrderQty should eliminate the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the JOIN to OrderQty like this should eliminate the duplicates:

```
INNER JOIN dbo.OrderQtyTable 
ON dbo.OrderHeader.JobNumber = dbo.OrderQtyTable.JobNumber
AND dbo.OrderComponent.ComponentNumber = dbo.OrderQtyTable.ComponentNumber
```